# Error In Lua - Loop on map/list

Tags: lua, lua-table, aerospike

I wrote the following function: deleteStrings .
That gets as input map of words and their length (mapWords),
and list of words.(listWords)
I want to remove from the map, keys that don't exist in the list. 
I'm getting "lua error".

```
function deleteStrings(mapWords,listWords)
    local CleanedMap = mapWords

    for key in map.keys(mapWords) do
        if not contains(listWords,key) then
            CleanedMap=map.remove(CleanedMap,key)
        end
    end
end



function contains(list, word)
    for _, v in pairs(list) do
        if v == word then return true end
    end
    return false
end
```

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: Replace `CleanedMap=map.remove(CleanedMap,key)` with `map.remove(CleanedMap,key)`

Comment: Still an issue after Egor's suggestion?

Comment: Yes, the error still exists.
Actually, It seems that the error is thrown in the for loop into contains function. What is wrong there? (the list may be empty  - but not nil)

Comment: The type of listWords is userdata

Comment: What are the contents of your `mapWords` ? I assume that `mapwords` is an aerospike `map` data structure. If that's the case then make sure that it only contains integer, string, bytes, list, map types. Placing other types will result in lua run-time [errors](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api/map.html)

Comment: Hi ,
The issue is resolved,
I changed the loop on list to :  for i = 1, #listWords do, 
and access to listWords[i] , instead of pairs/ipairs .

Comment: I love that it starts at 1...ha

Comment: What line is the Lua error reported on?  That should help find where your problem is.